# Memory profiling -VisualVM and Virgo

Tags: java

Processor :

> 64 bit OS Ubuntu server 64 bit

JAVA :

```
java version "1.7.0_15"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.7) (7u15-2.3.7-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

I am trying to connect The Virgo Web Server from EclipseRT to Visual vm for memory profiling.

> Memory profiling is not available (Not available. Failed to read objects in target application. Check the logfile for details (use Help | About | Logfile).)

When i checked in the log if Vsual vm ,the Error in the Visual vm log as:

> "com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded"

```
Both uses same JVM Open jdk
Visual VM Overview

ID: 15414
Host: localhost
Main class: org.netbeans.Main
Arguments: --userdir /root/.visualvm/1.3.2 --branding visualvm

JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01, mixed mode)
Java: version 1.7.0_15, vendor Oracle Corporation
Java Home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
JVM Flags: <none>

Virgo Web server Overview

PID: 1483
Host: localhost
Main class: org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main
Arguments: -noExit

JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01, mixed mode)
Java: version 1.7.0_15, vendor Oracle Corporation
Java Home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
JVM Flags: <none>
```

When i googled it found both should run on same user. Visual vm is running as "root" and Virgo is running as "test" user.

I tried launching the viusal as test user but i got bellow error:

```
test@ubuntuz620:/home/random$ jvisualvm --jdkhome /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/lib/nbexec: line 66: cd: /home/random: Permission denied
/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/lib/nbexec: line 66: cd: /home/random: Permission denied
No protocol specified
No protocol specified
test@ubuntuz620:/home/random$
```

Thanks in advance Prakash

Attached with full log message for Viusalvm

---

```
 Log Session: Wednesday, March 20, 2013 10:52:38 AM IST
 System Info: 
  Product Version         = VisualVM 1.3.2
  Operating System        = Linux version 3.2.0-39-generic running on amd64
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 1.7.0_15; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 23.7-b01; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = OpenJDK Runtime Environment 1.7.0_15-b20
  Java Home               = /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
  System Locale; Encoding = en_IN (visualvm); UTF-8
  Home Directory          = /root
  Current Directory       = /home/sentinel
  User Directory          = /root/.visualvm/1.3.2
  Installation            = /usr/lib/visualvm/visualvm
                            /usr/lib/visualvm/profiler
                            /usr/share/netbeans/platform12
  Boot & Ext. Classpath   = /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/netx.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rhino.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/classes:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/pulse-java.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/java-atk-wrapper.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar
  Application Classpath   = /usr/share/netbeans/platform12/lib/boot.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/lib/org-openide-util.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/lib/locale/boot_ja.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/lib/locale/boot_pt_BR.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/lib/locale/boot_zh_CN.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_ja.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_pt_BR.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_zh_CN.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ja.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ja.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_pt_BR.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_zh_CN.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/lib/locale/org-openide-util_pt_BR.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/lib/locale/org-openide-util_zh_CN.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/lib/dt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar
  Startup Classpath       = /usr/share/netbeans/platform12/core/core.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/core/org-openide-filesystems.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/core/locale/core_ja.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_pt_BR.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/core/locale/core_pt_BR.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_ja.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/core/locale/core_zh_CN.jar:/usr/share/netbeans/platform12/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_zh_CN.jar:/usr/lib/visualvm/visualvm/core/com-sun-tools-visualvm-modules-startup.jar:/usr/lib/visualvm/visualvm/core/locale/core_visualvm.jar
```

---

```
INFO [org.netbeans.core.startup.NbEvents]: Turning on modules:
    org.openide.util.lookup [8.3.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.openide.util [8.6.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.openide.modules [7.17.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.openide.awt [7.23.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.api.progress/1 [1.20.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.openide.dialogs [7.15.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.openide.nodes [7.16.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.openide.windows [6.33.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.openide.io [1.23.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.core.io.ui/1 [1.8.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.openide.filesystems [7.38.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.mimelookup/1 [1.16.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.openide.text [6.30.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.swing.tabcontrol [1.21.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.swing.outline [1.9.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.openide.explorer [6.28.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.openide.actions [6.16.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.lib.profiler/1 [1.10.2 120606-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.lib.profiler.common/1 [1.10.2 120606-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.bootstrap/1 [2.33.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.core.startup/1 [1.25.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.spi.quicksearch [1.6.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.modules.queries/1 [1.19.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.openide.loaders [7.16.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.libs.jna/1 [1.7.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.modules.keyring [1.1.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.swing.plaf [1.16.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.core/2 [3.20.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.modules.options.api/1 [1.18.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.api.annotations.common/1 [1.5.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.modules.profiler.oql/0 [0.5.1 120606-unknown-revn]
    org.openide.execution [1.18.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.lib.profiler.charts/1 [1.6.1 120606-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.lib.profiler.ui/1 [1.9.2 120606-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.modules.profiler/1 [1.17.2 120606-unknown-revn]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.modules.startup [1.0 120606]
    org.netbeans.modules.settings/1 [1.26.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.core.windows/2 [2.21.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.uisupport/0 [1.0 120606]
    org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.services [1.20.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.modules.sendopts/2 [2.9.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.core/0 [1.4 120606]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.host/0 [1.0 120606]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.application/0 [1.4 120606]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.tools/0 [1.2 120606]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.modules.extensions/0 [1.5 110224]
    org.netbeans.core.nativeaccess/1 [1.7.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.ow2.chameleon.management.beans [0.9.1 0.9.1 091124]
    org.ow2.chameleon.management.visual [0.9 0.9 091120]
    com.sun.appserv.management [1.0 110224]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.host.remote/0 [1.0 120606]
    org.netbeans.core.ui/1 [1.22.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.jmx/0 [1.2 120606]
    org.netbeans.modules.progress.ui [1.12.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.modules.editor.mimelookup.impl/1 [1.9.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.profiling/0 [1.0 120606]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.profiler/0 [1.1 120606]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvmstat/0 [1.0 120606]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.modules.appui [1.0 120606]
    org.netbeans.modules.print [7.5.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    org.netbeans.modules.javame.profiler [1.0 090525]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.coredump/0 [1.0 120606]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.heapdump/0 [1.1 120606]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.threaddump/0 [1.0 120606]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.sampler [2.0 120606]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.sa/0 [1.0 120606]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.charts/0 [1.0 120606]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.application.views/0 [1.0 120606]
    org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.ui [1.16.1 100825-unknown-revn]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.host.views/0 [1.0 120606]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.modules.visualgc [2.1.1 100921]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.attach/0 [1.1 120606]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvm/0 [1.1 120606]
    net.java.visualvm.modules.glassfish [1.4 110224]
    com.sun.tools.visualvm.modules.buffermonitor/0 [1.5 110224]
    org.netbeans.modules.masterfs/2 [2.25.1 100825-unknown-revn]
Diagnostic information
Input arguments:
    -Djdk.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64
    -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni
    -Dnetbeans.system_http_proxy=http://web-proxy.sgp.hp.com:8080/
    -Dnetbeans.system_http_non_proxy_hosts=
    -Dnetbeans.dirs=/usr/lib/visualvm/visualvm:/usr/lib/visualvm/profiler:
    -Dnetbeans.home=/usr/share/netbeans/platform12
    -Xms24m
    -Xmx256m
    -Dnetbeans.accept_license_class=com.sun.tools.visualvm.modules.startup.AcceptLicense
    -Dsun.jvmstat.perdata.syncWaitMs=10000
    -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
    -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false
Compiler: HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
Heap memory usage: initial 24.0MB maximum 227.6MB
Non heap memory usage: initial 23.2MB maximum 214.0MB
Garbage collector: PS Scavenge (Collections=8 Total time spent=0s)
Garbage collector: PS MarkSweep (Collections=1 Total time spent=0s)
Classes: loaded=4666 total loaded=4666 unloaded 0
INFO [org.netbeans.core.ui.warmup.DiagnosticTask]: Total memory 12,528,062,464
INFO [null]: Total physical memory 12,528,062,464
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Found same position 600 for both Menu/File/com-sun-tools-visualvm-jmx-impl-AddJMXConnectionAction-alwaysEnabled.shadow and Menu/File/org-netbeans-modules-javame-profiler-ImportWtkSnapshotAction.instance
INFO [com.sun.tools.visualvm.attach.AttachModelImpl]: printFlag
com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:106)
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:63)
    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:213)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.attach.AttachModelImpl.getVirtualMachine(AttachModelImpl.java:124)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.attach.AttachModelImpl.getVirtualMachine(AttachModelImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.attach.AttachModelImpl.printFlag(AttachModelImpl.java:89)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvm.JVMImpl.isDumpOnOOMEnabled(JVMImpl.java:212)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.heapdump.impl.HeapDumpOnOOMEAction.updateState(HeapDumpOnOOMEAction.java:83)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.heapdump.impl.HeapDumpOnOOMEAction.isEnabled(HeapDumpOnOOMEAction.java:77)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.heapdump.impl.HeapDumpOnOOMEAction.isEnabled(HeapDumpOnOOMEAction.java:46)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.actions.SingleDataSourceAction.updateState(SingleDataSourceAction.java:77)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.heapdump.impl.HeapDumpOnOOMEAction.updateState(HeapDumpOnOOMEAction.java:98)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.actions.DataSourceAction.initialize(DataSourceAction.java:90)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.actions.DataSourceAction.doInitialize(DataSourceAction.java:122)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.actions.DataSourceAction.isEnabled(DataSourceAction.java:99)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.explorer.ExplorerContextMenuFactory.getActions(ExplorerContextMenuFactory.java:171)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.explorer.ExplorerContextMenuFactory.getSelectionActions(ExplorerContextMenuFactory.java:127)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.explorer.ExplorerContextMenuFactory.getActions(ExplorerContextMenuFactory.java:121)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.explorer.ExplorerContextMenuFactory.createPopupMenu(ExplorerContextMenuFactory.java:73)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.explorer.ExplorerComponent.displayContextMenu(ExplorerComponent.java:205)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.explorer.ExplorerComponent.access$800(ExplorerComponent.java:70)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.explorer.ExplorerComponent$ExplorerTreeMouseAdapter.mousePressed(ExplorerComponent.java:248)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:280)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6502)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3312)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.explorer.ExplorerComponent$1.processMouseEvent(ExplorerComponent.java:112)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4489)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
[catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.autoupdate.updateprovider.AutoupdateCatalogParser]: http://visualvm.java.net/uc/release132/updates.xml.gz?unique=0d024cfda-1513-4fe5-a510-4c3f07ec2cbe_d9068500-fc6f-48c3-bd0e-3ccef01d3714:224:18: The content of element type "module_updates" must match "((notification?,(module_group|module)*,license*)|error)".
INFO [com.sun.tools.visualvm.attach.AttachModelImpl]: getSystemProperties
com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:106)
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:63)
    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:213)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.attach.AttachModelImpl.getVirtualMachine(AttachModelImpl.java:124)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.attach.AttachModelImpl.getVirtualMachine(AttachModelImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.attach.AttachModelImpl.getSystemProperties(AttachModelImpl.java:56)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvm.JVMImpl.getSystemProperties(JVMImpl.java:286)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.application.views.overview.ApplicationOverviewModel.initialize(ApplicationOverviewModel.java:229)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.application.views.overview.ApplicationOverviewModel.initialize(ApplicationOverviewModel.java:135)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.application.views.overview.ApplicationOverviewView.willBeAdded(ApplicationOverviewView.java:56)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.DataSourceView.viewWillBeAdded(DataSourceView.java:163)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.DataSourceWindowManager.addViews(DataSourceWindowManager.java:247)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.DataSourceWindowManager.openWindowAndAddView(DataSourceWindowManager.java:181)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.DataSourceWindowManager.access$000(DataSourceWindowManager.java:50)
[catch] at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.DataSourceWindowManager$1.run(DataSourceWindowManager.java:100)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(Unknown Source)
INFO [com.sun.tools.visualvm.attach.AttachModelImpl]: getSystemProperties
com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.<init>(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:106)
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(LinuxAttachProvider.java:63)
    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:213)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.attach.AttachModelImpl.getVirtualMachine(AttachModelImpl.java:124)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.attach.AttachModelImpl.getVirtualMachine(AttachModelImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.attach.AttachModelImpl.getSystemProperties(AttachModelImpl.java:56)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.jvm.JVMImpl.getSystemProperties(JVMImpl.java:286)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.profiler.ProfilerSupport.classSharingBreaksProfiling(ProfilerSupport.java:118)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.profiler.ApplicationProfilerView.willBeAdded(ApplicationProfilerView.java:147)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.DataSourceView.viewWillBeAdded(DataSourceView.java:163)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.DataSourceWindowManager.addViews(DataSourceWindowManager.java:247)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.DataSourceWindowManager.openWindowAndAddView(DataSourceWindowManager.java:181)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.DataSourceWindowManager.access$000(DataSourceWindowManager.java:50)
[catch] at com.sun.tools.visualvm.core.ui.DataSourceWindowManager$1.run(DataSourceWindowManager.java:100)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to ssh the server using test user?
Try

```
ssh test@yourmachine -X
```

This is because ssh-ing with one user and then running jvisualvm using sudo from another user may cause this problem...

By the way, what worked for me was copying the .Xauthority file as is (note this is a binary file) from root home directory to the home directory of the specific user (test in your case).